# There seems to be some disagreement about the "Minecraft" and "Pocket Minecraft" tags

Tags: support, minecraft

Someone's just gone through and added the [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag to all the [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition)

Seems like someone previously went through and removed all of those tags.

Thought I should bring this to meta's attention.

Comment: No, there isn't disagreement...someone basically spammed a bunch of inappropriate edits by adding minecraft to pocket minecraft questions

Comment: Definitely not the way it's supposed to work; they're two different games.

Comment: Yes, @DanielPalamarchuk seems to have done this. And in bulk too.

Comment: [I brought this to the attention of chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8279538#8279538) right around the same time you posted this.  The situation has been dealt with.

Answer (score 3):

I have reverted all the retagging done by this user.  The serial upvoting script should catch his expanded privileges (he got super upvoted just a short while ago), and reverse the upvotes, thereby removing his ability to retag questions.

I spent some time while I was at reviewing and fixing some of the questions, too, so they should be a bit neater.

Still definitely not something that should be done, but the end result is (slightly) higher quality content.

Comment: [This user](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/43045/viktoriya-palamarchuk) might be involved.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ Doing some digging, there's lots of correlation between the two users.  Almost certainly a sockpuppet.

Comment: @fbuecekert Similar names do not mean they are sock puppets.  Is there anything to back this up? (I'm not attacking you, I'm just curious as to how it's "almost certainly" a sock puppet

Comment: @Retrosaur As we discussed in chat, there are points you can look at and match up to draw a pretty accurate conclusion.  I'm not going to go into details, but between the vote reversal and some other data points, I am quite confident that there's some shenanigans between those users.

Comment: @Retrosaur The gap between "Your sister/mum/missus going and upvoting your questions out of love" and "Your dummy account blindly upvoting your questions because that's its job" still doesn't mean good votes.

Comment: The serial upvoting has happened on Board and Card Games as well as History.  The difference being two or three votes doesn't count for much, whereas all of a user's answers (where all > 10) can have quite an impact.